# Print the column which contains only the mix of alphabets & numbers

Tags: regex, shell, awk, grep

Is there any one liner to print the lines which contain only the mix of alphabets & numbers in a file?

I tried the following. But it doesn't work out.

```
awk '{print $3}' test.log | grep -o '.[0-9][a-zA-Z]*'
```

**EDIT**:

Content of test.log:

```
aaa bbb 1 ccc 
aaa mmm a1 nnn 
ooo bbb bc12 dm
```

My intention here is to print: a1 & bc12.

Comment: Print whole line? That could be grep -E "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$" test.log

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you want to `print` the third column (`$3`) where the third column matches (`~ / ... /`) an alphabet character `[a-zA-Z]` and (`&&`) a numeric character (`[0-9]`) (in any order) and nothing but alpha-numerics (`!~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/`):

```
% awk '$3 ~ /[a-zA-Z]/ && $3 ~ /[0-9]/ && $3 !~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ {print $3}' test.log
a1
bc12
```

Alternatively, this will match the third column where it starts with (`^`) one or more (`+`) alphabetical characters and is followed by and finishes with (`$`) a digit:

```
% awk '$3 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$/ {print $3}' test.log
a1
bc12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
grep -Eio '\b([a-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-z])[0-9a-z]*\b' test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` only:

```
$ grep -io '[A-Z]\+[0-9]\+' test.log
a1
bc12
```

Answer (score 0):

Not regex but...

```
print '\n'.join(x for x in mystring.split() if 0 < sum(map(str.isalpha, x)) < len(x))
```